# Python error with lambda and alphanumeric words

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I am really new to python and now I am having an error and do not know why I get this error.

I have 3 lists with words. The lists contains words numeric, literal words and  alphanumeric words. These lists are saved in an txt file. Each file can contain words from other lists or new words.

Now I like to compare these lists and copy all words without duplicates in to the new list. So I have one big list, containing all words but no duplicates.

This is my script:

```
file_a = raw_input("File 1?: ")
file_b = raw_input("File 2?: ")
file_c = raw_input("File_3?: ")
file_new = raw_input("Neue Datei: ")

def compare_files():

    with open(file_a, 'r') as a:
        with open(file_b, 'r') as b:
            with open(file_c, 'r') as c:
                with open(file_new, 'w') as new:
                    difference = set(a).symmetric_difference(b).symmetric_difference(c)
                    difference.discard('\n')
                    sortiert = sorted(difference, key=lambda item: (int(item.partition(' ')[0])
                                                                    if item[0].isdigit() else float('inf'), item))

                    for line in sortiert:
                        new.write(line)

k = compare_files()
```

When I run the script I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestProject1.py", line 19, in <module>
    k = compare_files()
  File "TestProject1.py", line 13, in compare_files
    sortiert = sorted(difference, key=lambda item: (int(item.partition(' ')[0])
  File "TestProject1.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    if item[0].isdigit() else float('inf'), item))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12234thl\n'
```

Anyone an idea or something what is wrong in my script?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Well, what number would you expect `'12234thl\n'` to be?

Comment: What is the sorting order you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You're simply trying to turn an alphanumeric string into an integer

Comment: So I have to change the value of the words to string.     I am trying to sort that in my new list is sorted. Starting 1, 2, ..., 11, 12,... , Ending with zzzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`partition` on `' '` or any other string for that matter will not extract the numeral part of the string except you know the character immediately following the numeral; very unlikely.

You can instead use a regular expression to extract the leading numeral part of the string:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'^\d+')

def compare_files():

    with open(file_a, 'r') as a, open(file_b, 'r') as b, \
         open(file_c, 'r') as c, open(file_new, 'w') as new:
         difference = set(a).symmetric_difference(b).symmetric_difference(c)
         difference.discard('\n')
         sortiert = sorted(difference, 
                           key=lambda item: (int(p.match(item).group(0)) \
                                             if item[0].isdigit() \
                                             else float('inf'), item))

         for line in sortiert:
             new.write(line)
```

The pattern `'^\d+'` should match all numerals from the start of the string and then `p.match(item).group(0)` returns the numeral as a string which can then *casted* to integer.

Comment: I implemented your changes and now its working perfectly. Thank you :)